# Xamarin Forms iOS Project - reset simulator required after storyboard modification

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard, ios-simulator

I'm in the process of creating a storyboard for the iOS project in my xamarin forms solution. In the iOS Simulator, I have to click "Reset Contents and Settings" after each change to the storyboard, to see my latest changes. This seems wrong. Is there a bug here?

Comment: Have you tried forcing a complete rebuild of your solution before deploying?

Comment: 1) Have you tried just deleting your application, not resetting everything?
2) As long as you mentioned Xamarin Forms, how do you combine Forms and Storyboard?

Comment: 1. I've tried deleting the bin and obj folders, if that's what you mean, but that didn't help.  2. The storyboard is only added to the iOS project, apparently a storyboard or a splash screen is now required.